# Can $(a_n)_n$ with $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert = \infty$ be a null sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence with $a_n \neq 0 \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

How do I proof that it is impossible that

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right\rvert = \infty$

at the same time?

If this claim is wrong please tell my why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both limits are possible to happen together. Just consider

$$\begin{cases}a_{2n+1}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\\ a_{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2n}\end{cases}$$ It is clear that $a_n\to 0.$ The other limit follows from

$$\dfrac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n}}=\dfrac{2n}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\to\infty.$$